# How to use defaulted and deleted functions C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I recently tried to learn about the defaulted and deleted functions in C++ 11 and i wrote the sample code below. When I try to run it says :

> error C2065: 'default' : undeclared identifier

the Code :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    int age;

    A(int x): age(x){};
    A() = default;

};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A test(10);
    cout << test.age << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a compiler which supports C++11 or enable the settings for same.[The code should work fine](http://ideone.com/Sh2Dt)

Comment: i use the Visual Studio 2012 RC

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you are using Microsoft Visual Studio. I'm sorry but the Microsoft compiler doesn't allow this new syntax even in the new version VC11.

Check the list of the available features [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx). You will see that *Defaulted and deleted functions* isn't yet available.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio with the MSVC++ compiler [does not support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) defaulted and deleted functions. You'll need to use something like [MinGW's](http://www.mingw.org/) G++.

Comment: is there a way to customize the VSVC++ compiler to use the MinGW G++ ??

Comment: No, you can't tell a compiler to use another compiler. However, you can tell visual studio to use a different compiler. I found this (http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/mingw/). I don't see why you'd use visual studio then though.