# C++ class special member functions default and delete VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

Using C++11 is it possible to specify class special member functions as defaulted and deleted?
I'm using Visual Studio 2012 version 11.0 and trying to set some class constructor as defaulted. Need to say this is abstract class and IDE underscores this code part as wrong. Also when I modify this class not to be abstract, the situation is the same.

```
class IProgressObserver {
public:
    IProgressObserver() =default;
    virtual ~IProgressObserver(){}
    virtual void reportProgress(void* reporter,
                                std::int32_t done,
                                std::int32_t total) = 0;    
};
```

Comment: Related / outdated duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12367473/420683

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can default special member functions in C++11, but VS11 does not support that.

Support has been added in VS12 (2013) -- but not for move constructors / assignment-operators.

See [MSDN: Support For C++11 Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx)